# create a cvs file based on the results retrieving from MySql (windows)

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I have the following code to create a cvs file based on the results retrieving from MySql:

```
import MySQLdb as dbapi
import sys
import csv
dbServer='127.0.0.1'
dbPass='Mydatabases#0'
dbSchema='myblog'
dbUser='root'
dbQuery="SELECT link,repo_name,dataset_id,title,(Select(replace(REPLACE(description, '\r', ''),'\\',''))) FROM myblog.testseprator INTO OUTFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads/readSQL/annotation.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ";
db=dbapi.connect(host=dbServer,user=dbUser,passwd=dbPass)
cur=db.cursor()
cur.execute(dbQuery)
# result=cur.fetchall()
db.close();
```

But when I checkout the file, it is all messed up! I see several /N, the content of a field is in another field! How can I fix that?

Comment: Have you considered using python to write your csv after you store the results into a variable?  In my experience, any sql library in python has less functionality than a desktop gui and so I typically just use them to obtain the data.  From there, writing to a csv in python is a breeze

Comment: @bjpreisler, as you can see in the code, the results  are saved to C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads/readSQL/annotation.csv

Comment: I think you're missing my point (or I'm missing yours).  You're trying to save your results by using the library MySQLdb.  What has worked for me is to store the results into a result variable (like you have hashed out), and then use a csv writer to separately write the file (not from within the query execution).  I realize my first comment was ambiguous.  What I meant was consider using a different library than your sql library to write the cvs

Comment: @bjpreisler, here is what I did, after saving the file in my local drive, I opened the file with notpad+, then, copy the whole content. Next, I opened Excel and used paste special to paste the content there. I am sorry, I am new to Python, if this not correct, can you please guide me what the best way for achieving my goal is?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving the file to your local drive, save it to the variable

```
result = cur.fetchall()
```

From there, proceed to use a csv writing library such as xlsxwriter or csv

```
import xlsxwriter
```

And follow the examples and documentation online how to write what you want and save as csv in a specific location on your computer

http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_demo.html

https://pymotw.com/2/csv/